# Is generating automatic requests illegal?

Tags: html, security, web-scraping, scripting, automated-tests

TL; DR;

Is generating automated requests to a government site illegal in some way?

---

There is a government site that provides a WebChat service as a contact option. When the chat is active there is a green button, otherwise, it is grey. It is almost impossible to find the green button (although sometimes it is green) so I decided to test the real availability of this service.

My idea was to create a script that accesses the website, checks the status of the button and then logs it. My goal was not to DDoS the server or something similar so I thought a request every minute will suffice for getting some statistics.

Could this be considered illegal? I know it might depend on each country's laws but if someone in the field could provide some insight or directions is really appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a legal question, off-topic for SO.

Comment: I understand your point. It could be related to InfoSec, QA or Law sites, what is your suggestion?

Comment: My guess is Law, but I'm not sure, please look at their guidance on questions.